# how to get visual c# express application instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using `visual c# express edition` and i want to create that application instance to get output window object.So i have used below code for creating visual studio instance.

```
DTE2 dte = (DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
```

but this is giving  exeception :

```
Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))
```

so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2013 Express, then the following works:

```
DTE2 dte = (DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("WDExpress.DTE.12.0");
```

In more generality, you can search for all running objects using the approach in [Get current visual studio instance (EnvDTE) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186330/get-current-visual-studio-instance-envdte-in-c-sharp)