# Get current visual studio instance (EnvDTE) in C#

Tags: c#

How can I get the current instance (EnvDTE) of visual studio in C #?

if you have multiple processes visual studio with the following line of code I get the object `EnvDTE80.DTE2`:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0");
```

At this point how can I get the current solution?

Comment: Define "current instance".

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask] before asking a question.

Comment: Opened a new question to save my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205933/how-do-i-get-the-dte-for-running-visual-studio-instance/14205934#14205934 and the current solution name is simple: dte.Solution.FullName

Comment: Quite obviously, "current instance" means the instance you're running your application in. I really don't understand why this question is closed as "vague"

Answer (score 4):

Use the running object table to get all instances, then select the one you want.

I don't think you can do better than this. It is similar to the way you attach a debugger to a VS instance. You have to select one from a list.

```
IEnumerable<DTE> GetInstances()
{
    IRunningObjectTable rot;
    IEnumMoniker enumMoniker;
    int retVal = GetRunningObjectTable(0, out rot);

    if (retVal == 0)
    {
        rot.EnumRunning(out enumMoniker);

        IntPtr fetched = IntPtr.Zero;
        IMoniker[] moniker = new IMoniker[1];
        while (enumMoniker.Next(1, moniker, fetched) == 0)
        {
            IBindCtx bindCtx;
            CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx);
            string displayName;
            moniker[0].GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out displayName);
            Console.WriteLine("Display Name: {0}", displayName);
            bool isVisualStudio = displayName.StartsWith("!VisualStudio");
            if (isVisualStudio)
            {
               var dte = rot.GetObject(moniker) as DTE;
               yield return dte;
            }
        }
    }
}

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern void CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable prot);
```

Comment: You forgot to answer the question.  How does he know which one is the "current instance"?  Avoid posting good answers to crappy questions.  Note that you could consider editing the question so at least the answer makes sense.

Comment: @HansPassant will do if the answer is accepted... or nothing happens in a few days.

Comment: @HansPassant has a point - while this is absolutely the way to get the currently running EnvDTE instances, the question itself is vague at best and nonsensical at worst.

Comment: Since this is closed I added http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205933/how-do-i-get-the-dte-for-running-visual-studio-instance/14205934#14205934