# How to get Visual Studio Output Window content via EnvDTE (Non Package)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, envdte

I'm writing an out of process console program that automate Visual Studio (2012). 
i need to get the content of the output pane either read it at once or preferably register to a notification on each line added to the output window.

I've seen some examples that only apply when writing a package, but they won't apply when doing so for an out of process program.

the big problem at the moment is that i can't get the output window service via GetService of a Service Provider. it always returns null.
I'm not sure i can get it if i'm not writing a package.

Comment: Are you getting a reference to a currently running instance?  This can be very tricky.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205933/how-do-i-get-the-dte-for-running-visual-studio-instance/14205934#14205934

Comment: i am actually the one creating it using: 

var vsType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0");
_dte = Activator.CreateInstance(vsType) as DTE2;

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me

```
public string GetOutput()
{
    const string buildOutputPaneGuid = "{1BD8A850-02D1-11D1-BEE7-00A0C913D1F8}";
    const string vsWindowKindOutput = "{34E76E81-EE4A-11D0-AE2E-00A0C90FFFC3}";
    var outputWindow = dte.Windows.Item(/*EnvDTE.Constants.*/vsWindowKindOutput);
    var outputWindowDynamic = outputWindow.Object;

    foreach(OutputWindowPane pane in outputWindowDynamic.OutputWindowPanes)
    {
        if (pane.Guid == buildOutputPaneGuid)
        {
            try
            {
                pane.Activate();
                var sel = pane.TextDocument.Selection;
                sel.StartOfDocument(false);
                sel.EndOfDocument(true);
                return sel.Text;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Filip, I tried to implement your code into my project but am getting the following error: "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{496B0ABE-CDEE-11D3-88E8-00902754C43A}' failed due to the following error: 'No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))' and the COM component does not support IDispatch::Invoke calls for DISPID_NEWENUM." Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Not really. Is your output pane visible?

Comment: Ultimately I realised that I needed to get after the ErrorList for what I was doing and not the output window, so I did not end up needing your code after all. Thanks anyways though!